# How to Convert Feet Into Meters?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class feetToMeters {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        final double feetToMeters = 0.305;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("Enter a value for feet: ");
        double value = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println (value + " feet is " + " meters " + meters);
    }
}
```

What else do I need to add for to convert feet to meters? Thanks!

Comment: You also need to switch the string and the variable "meters" in your final println so that it reads correctly.

Comment: You're missing exactly what you would have to do as if you were converting this by hand. Did you google how to do the conversion?

Comment: How can you attempt to learn how to write code when you can't even convert units?  This is grammar school arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, I did google but i didn't get the right answer. I tried 
double meteres = value * feetToMeters; as A. R. S. said. It might be not useful for you but it might be useful for someone who just started learning Java like me without instructor. I have reason why i do not have instructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class feetToMeters {

  public static void main (String [] args) {   
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

  System.out.println ("Enter a value for feet: ");
  double value = input.nextDouble();
  double meters = value/3.2808;
  System.out.println (value + " feet is " + meters + " meters ");

    }
}
```

Comment: This one also works.
System.out.println ("Thanks");

Comment: System.out.println("you are welcome");

Answer (score 4):

You have the conversion value right there, `0.305`. This number signifies how many *meters* are equal to 1 *foot*, so to figure out how many meters are equal to `value` number of feet we simply multiply:

```
double meters = value * feetToMeters;
```

Answer (score 2):

With your variable names, you would need:

`double meters = value * feetToMeters;`